# Installing Redmine on an NSlu2-Linux Device (QNAP)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I would like to run redmine on my NSlu2 NAS Server (QNAP) with an arm processor. I installed ipkg and so on everything runs well.

Trying to install redmine I need to install ruby-on-rails. The problem is that the my repositories install ruby version 1.9.1 which is too new for redmine and is not going to work. Does anyone know how I can downgrade ruby to 1.8.6 or 1.8.7?

Many thanks,
Ovanes

P.S.: I could probably compile the right version, but I don't like this idea. Preferred solution would be either some package I can download or the link to alternative repository.

P.P.S.: getting the pre-release Redmine version 0.9.0 started the db population script, but than it blames that I should install mysql gem. Running

```
gem install mysql
```

As well as other variation when specifying my-sql-config directory does not help I get the error:

```
# gem install mysql
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/opt/bin/ruby extconf.rb install mysql
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more
details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/opt/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
/opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:362:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:415:in `try_link0'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:419:in `try_link'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:527:in `try_func'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:772:in `block in have_func'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:668:in `block in checking_for'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in `open'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:274:in `block in postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:248:in `open'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:270:in `postpone'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:667:in `checking_for'
from /opt/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:771:in `have_func'
from extconf.rb:50:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. The suggested mkmf.log is empty. I assume that I don't have mysql source installed, but where can I get it as an Optware-Package which plays with mysql version installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TOTAL shot in the dark here:

If you have ruby 1.9.1 installed try installing RVM (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) with `gem install rvm`

Then you can `rvm install ruby-1.8.7 --head` and then `rvm ruby-1.8.7` to switch to ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Unfortunately, that neither works. After doing updates, installing all the stuff I get the error message, that sed and awk face unexpected tokens in autoconf and am not so eager to go the the autoconf and check what's wrong with that calls. But that was really a great suggestion if it would work.

Comment: Actually it worked! I missed, that I did not have sed and awk, those were symbolic links to busybox. After installing them I successfully switched to ruby 1.8.6 and was able to create the databases. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, which device do you have -- an NSLU2 or a QNAP TS series?  I don't think the NSLU2 would have the grunt to run a Rails site well, but the QNAP TS-[124]09 would be pretty good.

I'd replace the stock firmware (regardless of what it is) with Debian (which is reported to run [very nicely on the QNAP series](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/orion/qnap/)) and then use the packages from there.  `ipkg` repos tend to be a bit more exciting and fragmented, and a lot less supported, than Debian, so you'll find it easier to get assistance using them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May be I mix up smth. but I thought QNAP TS series runs NSLU2 Linux. I don' like the idea of throwing away all the QNAP apps which I use now...

Comment: Despite that I have TS-419 which is reported at this site as not being fully ported :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough disk space available, have you thought about installing debian in a chroot? That way you still would have the original software available but also a complete debian installation.

Comment: mmmm... Which OS will that NAS boot than? How is it possible to have two OSes installed?

Comment: The way I'm thinking, the one provided by the vendor. The debian install just has to work using that kernel. Which I'm not sure it will, but the chances are good. Read up on [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). And ask if there's something that still eludes you.